# pyspark insert failed using spark.read method

Tags: pyspark

```
def QueryDB(sqlQuery):
  jdbcUrl = mssparkutils.credentials.getSecret("param1","DBJDBCConntring","param3")
  spark=SparkSession.builder.appName("show results").getOrCreate()
  
  dbcdf = (spark.read.format("jdbc")
                    .option("url", jdbcUrl)
                    .option("query", sqlQuery)
                    .load()
              )

  return jdbcdf  

df= QueryDB("INSERT INTO schema.table1 (column1, column2) output inserted.column1 values('one', 'two')")
df.show()
```

the notebook runs without any error but no rows are inserted. any suggestion or sample code to insert into table.

Comment: Did you register your function as `udf`?

Answer (score 0):

`spark.read.format("jdbc")` is to **read** JDBC. If you want to insert data to JDBC you'd want something like this

```py
jdbcDF.write \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql:dbserver") \
    .option("dbtable", "schema.tablename") \
    .option("user", "username") \
    .option("password", "password") \
    .save()
```